# Query Totaling Multiple columns and grouping by another

Tags: sql, grouping

I am trying to get some totals of multiple records based on Location - but get totals for multiple columns to present back - basically there are various locations and each location has different species and totals at that location.

Without doing something really ugly - I have no idea of the best approach - any suggestions?

I have a table
Record
RecordID, Location,   Species1, Species2, Species3

---

1, Loc1, 3, NULL,1
2, Loc2, NULL, 12, NULL
3, Loc2, 2, 2, 2
4, Loc1, 1, 2, 3
5, Loc4, 3, NULL, NULL

I need to get the following data like this:

Location | Species1 | Species2 | Species3
Loc1 | 4 | 2 | 4
Loc2 | 2 | 14 | 2
Loc4 | 3 | NULL | NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT Location,
       SUM(ISNULL(Species1, 0)) AS Species1,
       SUM(ISNULL(Species2, 0)) AS Species2,
       SUM(ISNULL(Species3, 0)) AS Species3
FROM Record
GROUP BY Location
```

Comment: LOL - I had that almost the same and didn't see that - shameful on me ;!  Thanks

Comment: No problem. Anytime :)